# Why can't I see "fail" level log output in Application Insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I am seeing other trace records in Log Analytics but an exception in my app caused the following to be written to the console, locally.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
...stack
...lines
```

I cannot find any high sev... actually I cannot see anything logged by the Microsoft loggers at all.

I have the following configuration:

```
    "Logging": {
        "ApplicationInsights": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Warning",
                "MyRootNamespace": "Information"
            }
        },
    ...
```

My understanding is that the default is Warning, except for my own loggers which log at Information and higher. I'd expect to see the Fatal/fail trace from the Microsoft logger in Log Analytics.

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. How does your app insights configuration look like?
2. What .Net Core version are you using
3. Are you using the latest AI package versions?

Comment: I did not hear form you anymore, but you're welcome to take a look at [this demo repo](https://github.com/Ibis-Software/AppInsightsDemo/tree/master/src/AppInsightDemo) I set up  a while ago in which it works like you want. (If I understood your question correctly)

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for your time. AI isn't a popular tag so I shut SO down and got on with something else for the evening. That's the only config I have, just that and `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()` I'm using Core 2.2 and the 2.12.0 nupkg. I'm not at my desk so I'll look at your repo a bit later. Thanks again.

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks. Esp. the lifecycling, flushing. It doesn't answer my question but its useful nonetheless.

Comment: Do mind that unhandled exceptions do not show up as a trace in AI, but as an exception. You might be looking at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Peter has pointed out, the unhandled exception should be shown in the **exceptions** table, not in the **traces** table.

You can find the **exceptions** table as per the screenshot below:

[image]

If any more issues about this, please let me know.